# Loading Unicode data into Oracle

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, unicode

I'm trying to load the data ( which consists of unicode data aswell) into Oracle database.

When I just try to load the data to Oracle,

```
x =  str(Name)
```

Im getting the error:

```
ERROR: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ue030' in position 16: character maps to <undefined>
```

So, I used:

```
x =  str(Name)
   try:
      x = x.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
   except UnicodeDecodeError:
      x= x.encode('latin-1')

cursor.executemany(INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COL1) VALUES(:1), data)
```

When I converted the columns into dataframe printed x, I got it as , b'the data'
Then, when I checked the data in the Oracle database, I have like 4F4D43202D205570646174652050555247 ( some random digits).

How can I load the data properly into Oracle database using python?